# how to remove selected option from the drop down list in angular

Tags: angular

In my code i have a form array in which car names are displayed. When a button in form array to add car is clicked a select option box opens. I want that when one of the options from select is selected then that selected option get removed and when another option is selected than the  option selected previously get added to the list and the option which is selected now get removed from the list.

*my component.html code*

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<form class="forms" [formGroup]="addAnaGroupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addAnaGroupForm.value)">
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Car</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 txt-box ">
        <div class="addButton">
            <button
              [disabled]="disabledAddCar"
              type="button"

              (click)="addNewRow()"
              class="a-btns btn btn-success tab-btn"
            >
              Add Car
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="CarInfo">
            <div *ngFor="let itemrow of addAnaGroupForm.get('CarInfo')['controls']; let i = index "
                [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="form-group row">

                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Car Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 txt-box">

                        <select (change)="onChangeCar($event.target.value)" type="number" class="form-control"
 formControlName="CarNum">
    <option hidden value="">Please Select Car</option>
         <ng-container  *ngFor="let anaName of list">
          <option type="number"[ngValue]="anaName.Id">{{ anaName.CarName }}</option>
         </ng-container></select></div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" *ngIf="addAnaGroupForm.get('CarInfo')['controls']"
                (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="a-btns btn btn-success tab-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true">Delete</i>
              </button> </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

- my component.ts code*

  ```
        serverId: any;
     response = {
     status: "success",
     code: 200,
   payload: [
  {
    Id: 21,
    CarTypeId: 2,
    CarName: "car1"
  },
  {
    Id: 22,
    CarTypeId: 3,
    CarName: "car2"
  },

  {
    Id: 23,
    CarTypeId: 4,
    CarName: "car3"
  },
  {
    Id: 24,
    CarTypeId: 5,
    CarName: "car4"
  }
  ],
  error: [],
  message: "Car List"
  };
  list: any;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.addAnaGroupForm = this.fb.group({
  CarInfo: this.fb.array([])
  });
  }

  onChangeCar(value) {
  var str = value;
  this.serverId = str.substr(3);
  var index = this.response.payload.findIndex(x => x.Id == this.serverId);
  this.list.splice(index, 1);
  }

  aType() {
  this.list = this.response.payload;
  console.log(this.response);
  }

  get formArr() {
  return this.addAnaGroupForm.get("CarInfo") as FormArray;
  }

  initItemRows() {
  return this.fb.group({
  CarNum: [""]
  });
  }

  addNewRow() {
  this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
  this.aType();
   }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
  this.formArr.removeAt(index);
  }
  ```

When an option is selected it does not display the name.
Here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i56ede?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: The provided stackblitz app won't open for me.

Comment: Sorry for that. Here is updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i56ede?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Before deleting the element you can temporarily save it as `selectedCar` or something in your component. Whenever `onChangeCar ` triggers, you add the `selectedCar` back into the list and replace by it by the new emitted value.